# Swagger throws "Swagger Error Not a valid parameter definition" for body parameter

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

This is my input:

```
  parameters:
    - name: body
      in:  body
      required: true
      type: object
      description: | 
        The body.
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/CsrRequest'
```

And it says this:

Details

```
 Object
code:  "ONE_OF_MISSING"
message:  "Not a valid parameter definition"
 path: Array [5]
 inner: Array [2]
level: 900
type:  "Swagger Error"
description:  "Not a valid parameter definition"
lineNumber: 24
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the `type: object` from the body as per [this issue](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/144).

```
parameters:
  - name: body
    in:  body
    required: true
    description: | 
      The body.
    schema:
      $ref: '#/definitions/CsrRequest'
```